# How to keep an unmanaged node position fixed when its width/height changes

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX how do I keep the location (x,y coords) of an unmanaged Node the same when the width/height of the node changes?

The node is unmanaged and laid out using: resizeRelocate.  This is working well but sometimes the node changes height or width and I would like to keep the current x,y coords.  i.e. the node changes size but doesn't move within the scene.

I've tried listening to the boundsInLocal property and checking for differences in the minY values but the node is still moving and calling resizeRelocate from within the boundsInLocal listener triggers another boundsInLocal update.

What would be the best way to resize and reposition the node so that I keep the x,y coords but can change the width/height?

Here's an example:

```
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.application.*;

public class SizeTest extends Application
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Application.launch (args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start (Stage stage)
    {

        try
        {

            VBox b = new VBox ();
            VBox other = new VBox ();
            other.setManaged (false);
            other.setPrefWidth (100);
            other.setStyle ("-fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-border-color: red; -fx-padding: 5px;");

            b.getChildren ().add (other);

            VBox another = new VBox ();
            another.setPrefWidth (50);
            another.setMinHeight (50);
            another.setPrefHeight (50);
            another.setStyle ("-fx-background-color: blue;");

            Button but = new Button ("Push Me");
            but.setOnAction (ev ->
            {

                Button abut = new Button ("Another one");
                other.getChildren ().add (abut);

            });

            other.getChildren ().addAll (another, but);

            other.boundsInLocalProperty ().addListener ((p, oldv, newv) ->
            {

                double h = other.prefHeight (other.getPrefWidth ());

                other.resizeRelocate (other.getBoundsInParent ().getMinX (),
                                      other.getBoundsInParent ().getMinY (),
                                      other.getBoundsInParent ().getWidth (),
                                      h);

            });

            Scene sc = new Scene (b);
            stage.setScene (sc);
            stage.sizeToScene ();
            stage.show ();

            Platform.runLater (() ->
            {

                double h = other.prefHeight (other.getPrefWidth ());

                other.resizeRelocate (100,
                                      100,
                                      other.getPrefWidth (),
                                      h);

            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace ();

        }

    }

}
```

When you press the "Push Me" button another button is added to the container, it then overflows.  I'd like the "other" container to instead resize itself to its preferred size but keep its x,y coords.

The listener for the boundsInLocal property sort of does this but you'll notice the jump in position and incorrect sizing.  Removing the listener sizes and positions the node correctly but adding the new button overflows the container.

At this point I'm thinking of creating my own layout manager for this behavior.

Comment: Just pass the same value as the first 2 parameters to `resizeRelocate` and pass different parameters as the other 2...

Comment: Where would I do that?  I've tried it in a boundsInLocal property listener but you are then affecting the bounds while listening to them.  The node can change size/position without me affecting the bounds, i.e. layoutBounds isn't being updated.  The closest I've come to so far is listening to changes in boundsInLocal then calculating the new position based on the size change and the position change.

Comment: *"The node can change size/position without me affecting the bounds"* How? This question could really use an edit clarifying the issue. A [mcve] would certainly help...

Comment: You don't have to change the bounds directly on a node for it to change size/position.  If a child node decides to change size/position then the parent will change to accommodate it.  Imagine a button that changes size in response to being clicked, the parent node will change size but its bounds have not been directly modified.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution to this was to use a javafx.scene.layout.Pane.  My use case here was to have a number of popups appear above the content.  I used a StackPane with the "popup pane" being the top level with a transparent background.  The "popups" are added to the Pane and positioned with Node.relocate(x,y).  The pane handles sizing and will keep the popup at the specified x,y coords.  The pane keeps the popup at its preferred size so manual sizes changes should be made through the setPref* methods.

Addendum: while the above method works, because the popup pane would be a sibling of other children of the StackPane then events aren't delivered to the "lower levels", i.e. whatever is below the popup pane.

To get around this I added the content pane (the lower level) to the Pane and then tied the content pane's pref width/height to the size of the Pane.

i.e.

```
    this.popupPane = new Pane ();

    this.contentPane = new SplitPane ();
    this.contentPane.prefWidthProperty ().bind (this.popupPane.widthProperty ());
    this.contentPane.prefHeightProperty ().bind (this.popupPane.heightProperty ());
    this.popupPane.getChildren ().add (this.contentPane);
```